# how to find a file name using find command when the name can contain "_" and sometime may not contain

Tags: linux

In my directory there are multiple files and sometime file name contains "_" i am trying to find file names based on the ordernumber coming in the file name itself and update the filename

for e.g.

```
f3 =822220222 # order number that changes every time
f4=`find . -name *$f3*`  # command i am using to find the filename having this order number in name itself
# Files in directory are like
Filename_822220222_1 or Filename_822220222_1_1 or Filename_822220222 (e.g.)
```

Comment: OK, and... does it not work? what happens when you run that code? why is that the wrong result?

Comment: For first time it works , but when there is file with Filename_1 it throws error on find        find: paths must precede expression: filename_1 Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
mv: cannot stat '': No such file or directory

Comment: I also tried f4=`find . -name *$f3*_*` this works only when the file name has single time "_1" but not works without or in case of twice occurrence

Comment: Does the unspecified shell accept the first line?  At least for `bash` and others, given the space after `f3` an error would be expected, like  "f3: command not found"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
f4=$(find ./ -name "$f3*")
```

even if you will add the `_` it will work

Comment: f4=`$(find ./ -name "*$f3*")`                                                                                             
But it gave error first for Permission denied, after providing full permission also it failed   line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

Comment: @RohitShamdasani please mark the answer as solution